# setting cookies for checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, forms

this is the function i'm trying to set cookies for the chekboxes in my form

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){    
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ?
        "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function set_check(){
    var proceed = document.forms['form1']['proceed_opt[]'].checked;
    setCookie(proceed_opt[], proceed, 60*60*1);
    alert(proceed_opt[]);
}
```

and the check-boxes in my form are like this..

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I will upload new Image" onChange="set_check()";>
          Insert Option &quot;I will upload new Image&quot;
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
            &nbsp; 
          <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I approve this sample for a Night Light" onChange="set_check()";>
          Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">I approve this sample for a Night Light</font>&quot; 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">
            &nbsp; 
          <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="Select One" onChange="set_check()";>
          Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Select One</font>&quot; 
    </td>
</tr>     
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan='2'>
         &nbsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="other" onChange="set_check()">
          Insert Option &quot;Other See comments&quot;
    </td>
</tr>
```

But the cookies are not setting here...can anyone tell me how to set cookies for the check-boxes in the form...

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code.  I cleaned it up a little, and made some assumptions.  Basically, you're over-complicating things.

You were incorrectly referencing the fields, and there were errors.  This approach is simpler (though still not the ideal - but it works).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mAnUQ/

HTML:

```
<form name="form1">
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I will upload new Image" onChange="set_check(this)">
        <label for="check1">I will upload new Image</label>
    </div>
<div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I approve this sample for a Night Light" onChange="set_check(this)">
    <label for="check2">I approve this sample for a Night Light</label>
    </div>
<div>              
          <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="proceed_opt[]" value="Select One" onChange="set_check(this)">
    <label for="check3">Select One</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="proceed_opt[]" value="other" onChange="set_check(this)">
        <label for="check4">Other See comments</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){    
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ?
        "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function set_check(me){
    setCookie(me.value, me.checked, 60*60*1);
    console.log(me.value);
    console.log(me.checked);
    console.log(document.cookie)
}
```

Comment: I have tested and verified that this is setting the cookies.  Please explain how this is not solving your problem, because if that isn't what you need, then I don't think I understand well enough to help you.

Comment: no dude...i also tested this...after i checked a check-box and on page reload the check-box which is checked already should be there on the page itself but now it is not doing like this..

Comment: I think you're confusing the function of the cookie.  The cookie simply stores data, which in this case is done.  Then, if you want to use that data to pre-select the fields, you need to write code to do that as well.  It doesn't automatically save the state of the checkboxes.

Comment: yup u r absolutely right...just now observed that the cookie is set...but how can i get that cookie value into the form once the page reloads.....as u said some-thing like pre-select the fields..can u show me how can i write code for that functionality..

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to go to bed now, but I'll try to get you something tomorrow.  Start by splitting the cookie into name/value pairs `var cookies = document.cookie.split(/;/);` and then using those values to compare against each of the checkboxes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11404/discussion-between-abc123-and-mestek-webmaster)

Comment: Here's an example of how you can set the value of these checkboxes using PHP: `<?php if( isset($_COOKIE["I_approve_this_sample_for_a_Night_Light"]) && $_COOKIE["I_approve_this_sample_for_a_Night_Light"] == true) echo "checked='checked'";?>`

Comment: because the javascript is storing the cookie name as the checkbox value, and the cookie value of `true` if it is checked, and `false` if it is not, you need to reference the cookie by the checkbox value.

Comment: Also note that you must replace the spaces with underscores

Answer (score 0):

See if this might lead you in the right direction. This sets a cookie named "proceed_opt" with the value of the checked box.

HTML:

```
<form name="form1"><table><tr><td></td><td>&nbsp; <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I will upload new Image" onclick="if(this.checked){set_check(this);}">
      Insert Option &quot;I will upload new Image&quot;</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td colspan="2">
        &nbsp; 
      <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I approve this sample for a Night Light" onclick="if(this.checked){set_check(this);}">
      Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">I approve this sample for a Night Light</font>&quot; </td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="2">
        &nbsp; 
      <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="Select One" onclick="if(this.checked){set_check(this);}">
      Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Select One</font>&quot; </td></tr>     
 <tr><td></td><td colspan='2'> &nbsp;
 <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="other" onclick="if(this.checked){set_check(this);}">
     Insert Option &quot;Other See comments&quot;</td></tr>?</table></form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function set_check(proceed){

var proceed_opt = proceed.value;
setCookie("proceed_opt", proceed_opt, 60*60*1);
alert (proceed_opt);
}
```

Comment: @abc123 see revised post above.

Comment: the alert box is working dude...but the cookie is not set there when i refresh the page the selected check-box is not there...wat to do???